# How to get an insert out of the shaft again?

Tags: gear, archery

I've successfully rescued the last few inches of my carbon shaft. What I have is a piece of shaft containing the insert an the tip (the tip can be screwed out of course).

The insert is fixed with a [superglue gel from "Würth"](https://eshop.wuerth.de/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/1401-B1-Site/en_US/-/EUR/ViewModelDetail-ShowRecommendedModel;pgid=hpYggLKEB.wx_AKcRChw0ktH0000jkOE1z1-;sid=NwQyPcapUHU5PZDwTtAs4MmjzDCgpiaK568W2Q1B?CatalogCategoryID=MgoKD92eIAAAAAFBM60Z8IdN&CampaignName=CS005&RecoId=box1@productdetailpageA).

> Properties:
>
> ```
> Chemical basis: Ethyl-2-cyanoacrylate monomer
> Colour: Transparent
> Density: 1.05 g/cm³
> Min. tensile strength: 20 N/mm²
> Max. tensile strength: 30 N/mm²
> Conditions for tensile strength: in accordance with DIN 53288
> Min. combined tension and shear resistance: 25.5 N/mm²
> Max. gluing gap size: 0.25 mm
> Min. hardening time: 20 s
> Max. hardening time: 100 s
> Min./max. temperature conditions: -30 bis 80 °C
> Shelf life from production: 12 Month
> ```

I think that it doesn't make any differences, but it's a ["Easton Axis Traditional" carbon shaft](http://www.eastonhunting.com/products/arrows/axis-traditional) with a x-hit insert.

How do I get the insert out of the shaft again without damaging it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume by "damaging it" you refer to the insert. To remove it you have to heat the glue to a temperature where it melts.

If a part of the insert is visible, fixate it in a bar clamp. If not, put something in it like an old metal tip or anything metal that fits into the insert and fixate this in the bar clamp. Then you use what you have at your disposal to heat the part of the shaft, where the insert is inserted, e.g. a hot air gun, a burner, a lighter, .... While heating you continuously pull or twist (depending on whether there is a thread) the shaft and as soon as the glue melts, it will come off. An alternative way to heat it up is to use a soldering iron to transfer heat to the insert be directly pushing onto it.

If the insert is made of metal the heat is no problem at all, if it is made of some kind of synthetic it can obviously get damaged in this process. You can still try the same (apart of the soldering iron) very cautiously, but it may get damaged.

Comment: I have no archery experience, my answer is solely based on general DIY experience, so if there is anything "archery" specific that I missed, please correct me.

Comment: The solder gun is a good idea, much better than my propane torch... Of course I'm still using AL shafts.

Comment: Worked :) I used two forceps, one to hold the shaft and one to hold the tip. I held the "insert area" above a candle and gently but constantly pulled both forceps away from each other.